# Android service communicating to its parent Activity

Tags: android, service

I am writing a GPS tracking app that receives geo location updates from Google Play Services and calls my Activity's onLocationChanged(), where my activity plots the user's movement on a map on the screen.

The problem is that the above only works when my app is in the foreground, e.g. when I walk with my phone in my hand.  If I put it in my pocket and then turn on some time later, the app has no idea about where I was when I wasn't actively using the app.

To solve, this, I turned to Android Services, the idea being the following:
* My app starts a background service
* The service runs and listens for location updates from Google Play Services
* On location change, the service calls a method on my Activity and gives it the new location, so that the Activity can plot it on the map
* When my app is paused, stopped, and/or destroyed by the system, the service keeps running and gathering location data
* When I start my app again, it connects to the service and gets all the location data since the last communication.

I've studied chapters 33-36 (about Services) of this excellent Android textbook: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_of_Android_Started_and_Bound_Services

**But I still can't understand how a SERVICE can call an ACTIVITY.  (All the examples in the book demonstrate how the ACTIVITY can call a SERVICE to request data)... :-(  Please  help!**

Moreover, none of the following seems to offer the solution:
1. Started Service: seems to be for offloading long-running tasks from the UI thread
2. Intend service:  same as above
3. Bound service:  won't do the trick since it runs in the UI thread, so will get destroyed whenever my App gets destroyed

I'm at a loss... Please help

Comment: use a local bound service and setup a listener so that the service can call your activity's method directly

Comment: But since a local service runs in the same thread as the activity, won't the service be killed by the system if my Activity is stopped and the system decides to destroy it to conserve resources?  Or when my Activity is destroyed on screen orientation change?

Comment: No if you first call startService then bindService

Comment: Thanks, @pskink, this makes sense!  One more qq:  how do you set up a listener? (Unless what you meant was giving the service a reference to the activity, so that the service can make a method call on the activity...?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've dug around and figured out how to solve my own question above.

I use a Service that's:

- **Local**: runs in same thread as my Activity
- **Private**:  only my app can start/stop, bind/unbind it
- **Started**: I start it so that it doesn't get destroyed by the system on activity state changes, such as destroy/create on phone screen orientation
- AND **bound**: so that my Activity and Service can communicate throughout

To achieve two-way communication - the essence of my original question - i simply pass to the service a reference to my Activity by calling a public metod MyService.setActivity(MyActivity).  I do this on myConnection.onServiceConnected().  Once my service has a reference to the Activity, it can call the activity's methods.  For example, every time my service gets a new Location object from Google Play Services, it calls my activity's updateLocation(Location) method where the activity updates the map with the new point on the user's path.

The service lives continuously between being started and stopped, yet the Activity has a more flaky lifecycle (e.g. it gets destroyed and recreated on phone screen orientation changes).  To avoid the situation where my services makes a method call on the activity while the activity is not active, I pass a null Activity reference to my service before the activity gets deactivated, so that the service can check for non-nullness before calling the activity's methods.